# How to stop parsing other opts if past opts failed in nom.rs?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

Currently i have 2 methods: `parse_int` and `parse_string`. They return either one number or one string, respectively. For example, if i have the parser `tuple((parse_int, parse_string))`, then it will convert `" 123 sdf"` to `(123, "sdf")`.
My actual parser looks like `tuple((parse_string, opt(parse_int), opt(parse_string)))`. It will succesfully convert `" dsf 123 sdf"` to `("dfs", Some(234), Some("sdf"))`, which is good. But if I enter `"dfs sdf"` as input, then we get `("dfs", None, Some("sdf")))`. And I want it to return to me `("dfs", None, None))`, because `sdf` could not be converted to int. For a better understanding, I am making a command args parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tuple()` inside `opt()`, to tie `parse_int` and `parse_string` together:

```rust
tuple((parse_string, opt(tuple((parse_int, opt(parse_string))))))
```

It will produce `(&str, Option<(int, Option<&str>)>)` instead of `(&str, Option<int>, Option<&str>)`. You can use [`map()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.1/nom/combinator/fn.map.html) to flatten it if desired.

Comment: Not quite, this is what I thought but look carefully at their desired output for `"dfs sdf"`.

Comment: @orlp Are you saying because the double `None`? This is what I said you can flatten.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the fact they only want `"dfs"` as the output in that scenario, stopping on the first whitespace.

Comment: @orlp They also split by whitespaces in the successful scenario - so I think their parsers stop on whitespaces.

Comment: Not quite what I expected. What if i have 3 optional arguments, like this: `tuple((parse_string, opt(tuple((parse_string, opt(parse_int), opt(parse_string))))))`. This code will not correctly work for `" dfs sdf sdf"`. The only solution that came to mind is such a large parser `tuple((parse_string, opt(tuple((parse_string, opt(tuple((parse_int, opt(parse_string)))))))))` (it works). I think there are simpler options.

Comment: @olegshmel Indeed, nesting them is what I would do. You can create a helper parser combinator to do that, I don't think one exists in nom.